# While I keep my wrist down, how to keep playing audio in iWatch app? - watchOS

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchos

I am trying to build an audio app for apple watch. But the problem is whenever I keep my hands down , audio will stop playing.
I have turned background mode on as well.
Can anyone please help me with this? I am stuck at this part.
Here is the Code I have used for playing audio.

```
func play(url : URL) {
        do {
            if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 4.0, *) {
                WKExtension.shared().isFrontmostTimeoutExtended = true
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
            self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                player!.prepareToPlay()
            player?.delegate = self
            player?.play()
            print("-----------------")
            print("Playing Audio")
            print("*****************\nCurrent Time \(String(describing: self.player?.currentTime))")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            self.player = nil
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } catch {
            print("*************************")
            print("AVAudioPlayer init failed")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the code you have written so far so that we can try to help you.

Comment: you show add this method to mainRunLoop as selector Also make sure to add this method in Utility class Or In appDelegate Or may be in any other class that uis not getting Deinit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are trying to play with `Audio Data`, not `Audio URL` and have added `policy: .longFormAudio` in your category setup. As per [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/storyboard_support/playing_background_audio), these two settings have to be set for audio to play in background mode.

```
// Set up the session. 
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    
do {
    try session.setCategory(
        .playback,
        mode: .default,
        policy: .longFormAudio
    ) 
} catch let error {
    fatalError("*** Unable to set up the audio session: \(error.localizedDescription) ***") 
}
    
// Set up the player. 

let player: AVAudioPlayer 
do {
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(data: audioData) 
} catch let error {
    print("*** Unable to set up the audio player: \(error.localizedDescription) ***")
    // Handle the error here.
    return 
}
    
// Activate and request the route. 
session.activate(options: []) { (success, error) in
    guard error == nil else {
        print("*** An error occurred: \(error!.localizedDescription) ***")
        // Handle the error here.
        return
    }
        
    // Play the audio file.
    player.play() 
}
```

I have tested this code and its working with only Bluetooth connectivity in Watch application not in watch speaker.

Comment: In my case only the AudioPlayer(data:) was needed.policy: .longForm needs the user to set where he want the audio to be played. I let .default and the sound still playing in background too.

Comment: Does someone knows how to let it work with watch speaker? Every time that I'm putting the wrist down it's pausing the stream :(

Comment: @PietroMessineo, same code work on speaker as well please check that. i hope it is work for you

Comment: I tried that and it’s not work on speakers just because the policy .longForm is opening the alert for Bluetooth connection.

Comment: If found, that the setup needs to differentiate between Simulator and Device. When setting up for Simulator the 'policy' needs to be '.default' (Mac speaker will be the output route), when targeting the Device (Watch), set to '.longForm'.

Answer (score 1):

Simply turning on background mode is not enough. You also need to activate the `AVAudioSession`.
It's all well documented by Apple here: [Playing Background Audio](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/playing_background_audio).

> Configure and Activate the Audio Session
>
> Before you can play audio, you need to set up and activate the audio session.
>
> ```
> session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback,
>                     mode: .default,
>                     policy: .longForm,
>                     options: [])
> ```
>
> Next, activate the session, by calling the activate(options:completionHandler:) method.
>
> ```
> session.activate(options: []) { (success, error) in
>     // Check for an error and play audio.
> }
> ```
>
> <sub>Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/playing_background_audio</sub>

---

#### Example:

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer?
let session: AVAudioSession = .sharedInstance()

func prepareSession() {
    do {
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback,
                                mode: .default,
                                policy: .longForm,
                                options: [])
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func play(url: URL) {
    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    session.activate(options: []) { (success, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        // Play the audio file
        self.player?.play()
    }
}
```

---

#### Simple Test:

```
prepareSession()

if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "mp3") {
    play(url: url)
}
else {
    print("test.mp3 not found in project: put any mp3 file in and name it so")
}
```

Comment: This part is also included in the code. Still not working.

Comment: @hinalilad I did a quick PoC and got it working. You need to take a deep breath and recheck your work. Also, update your question with code related to `AVAudioSession` and ensure you have enabled "Background modes" for "Audio" in the App's WatchKit Extension target

Comment: @hinalilad Updated answer with appropriate code from my PoC for you reference

Comment: @ staticVoidMan I have checked everything you mentioned, but nothing seems to work :( .

Comment: Whenever I get out of the app or whenever screen goes off, the audio player stops playing audio.

Comment: @hinalilad If not top-secret, then share your project online. Lets us have a look.